# Run Command Prompt in XP mode in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, 64-bit, disk-operating-system

I am trying to run a DOS application (`.com`) in Windows 7 64bit. It will not run on anything newer than XP. Is there any way? I can set the comand prompt to run in XP compatibility mode?  The only options I'm seeing are Vista and Server 2008.

I have tried DOSBox, and I can't seem to get OS/2 to install under virtual box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows 7 64bit does not support a 16 bit sub system, so no 16bit DOS applications will run in Windows 7 64bit. Your title is not quite clear, Maybe you are using the wrong term, here is what XP Mode is, and may be the solution you are looking for.

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx

Comment: Correct, I meant XP compatibility, not XP mode as in a virtual machine.  Thanks.

Comment: @sound2man: No 16bit (and .com is always 16bit) apps on Windows 64bit (including XP 64bit). You have to use XP Mode or other VM (or reinstall WIn7 as 32bit).

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Never mind. I just noticed the 64bit part. You won't be able to get it working unless you use a VM as already mentioned.

You might want to download the Microsoft Compatability Toolkit from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=24da89e9-b581-47b0-b45e-492dd6da2971&displaylang=en

It will let you set all kinds of compatability settings for an application and will apply them everytime you start it (even from the command prompt).